# Incremental load for 3181 tables

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to fastly run my incremental pipeline in azure data factory for 3181 tables.

I have 3181 tables in database(i.e azure SQL database )I have loaded these tables in datawarehouse(I.e azure SQL database). After that everyday data is coming in production for that purpose I have created incremental pipeline in adf  so whatever the data has been coming into database will be incrementally loaded into datawarehouse tables. But whatever the pipeline I have created is taking long time like 12 hrs and more than 12 hrs . So I have segregated the tables in module level in pipeline . Each module may have 50tables ,some module have 100 tables etc .. so there are 51 modules for 3181 tables. So I have created 51 triggers for incremental pipeline based on parameter module and I have given one second gap for each schedule trigger . So there so much complexity in this . Is there any better approach

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating 51 triggers, you can use 1 pipeline and start all child pipeline one at a time.

1. have a list of pipelines to run in a json file or SQL table, and read that into a lookup activity
2. use a foreach loop on each row of the lookup
3. inside the foreach: a wait activity and then an execute pipeline activity

[image: pipeline]

Important: uncheck "wait on completion" so that pipelines will run parallel.

[image: wait on completion]